# Proof for binomial theorem $ (1+x)^a = \sum_{k=0}^\infty P_k(a)x^k $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

how can I prove the following for positive and negative integers as  power $a$ as well as rational powers $a$? I would prefer to prove it without differentiation and Taylor's theorem if that's possible. I think for positive integers it might be possible to solve it with induction but I can't come to any solution.

$$
(1+x)^a = \sum_{k=0}^\infty P_k(a)x^k
$$

$
P_k(a) = \frac1{k!}a(a-1)...(a-k+1)
$

($P_0(a)=1$)

Comment: First get the statement correct.  If $a$ is not a positive integer, you won't just have a sum from $k=0$ to $a$ (whatever that means), you'll have an infinite series.  See [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)

Comment: I already read that but that doesn't get me any further unfourtunately. But I already managed to prove it for positive integers

Answer (score 1):

Let’s use the Stirling numbers oft the first kind $\,\displaystyle {n\brack m}$

(e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind).

We have $\enspace\displaystyle \frac{(-1)^v}{v!} \sum\limits_{n=0}^v {v\brack n} (-a)^n = \frac{(-1)^v}{v!} (-a)(-a+1)…(-a+v-1) = {\binom a v}$

and because of  $\,\displaystyle {v\brack n}=0\,$ for $\,n>v\,$ it’s $\enspace\displaystyle \frac{(-1)^v}{v!} \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty {v\brack n} (-a)^n = {\binom a v} \,$ .

With $\,|x|<1\,$ follows:

$\enspace\displaystyle \sum\limits_{v=0}^\infty {\binom a v} x^v = \sum\limits_{v=0}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^v x^v}{v!} \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty {v\brack n} (-a)^n = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a^n \sum\limits_{v=0}^\infty  (-1)^{n-v}{v\brack n}\frac{x^v}{v!} $

$\hspace{2.2cm}\enspace\displaystyle = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a^n}{n!} (\ln(1+x))^n = e^{a\ln(1+x)}=(1+x)^a $